# Is there a way to add a parameter that supress the need of other parameters using argparse on Python?

Tags: python, argparse

I am using Argparse on python to do a script on command line. I have this for my script:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog = 'manageAdam')
parser.add_argument("-s", action='store_true', default=False, help='Shows configuration file')

parser.add_argument("d", type=str, help="device")
parser.add_argument("o", type=str, help="operation")
parser.add_argument("-v", "--value", type=int, nargs='*', help="value or list to send in the operation")
```

I am looking that if I call manageAdam -s it would work and don't ask for the positional arguments, something like the -h, which can be called without any other positional argument that is defined. Is it possible?

Comment: `-h` has a special Action class, one that prints the help and then does a system exit.  That's how it blocks other parameters.  There isn't a clean way of just exiting the parser from a specific action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this. You *might* be able to achieve something by writing some custom [`Action`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Action) classes that keep track on the parser about their state, but I believe it will become quite messy and buggy.

I believe the best bet is to simply improve your UI. The `-s` is **not** an option. It's a separate command that completely alters how your script executes. In such cases you should use the [`subparsers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers) functionality which allows to introduce sub-commands. This is a better interface then the one you thought, and is used by a lot of other tools (e.g. Git/mercurial).

In this case you'd have a `config` command to handle the configuration and a `run` (or how you want to call it) command to perform the operations on the device:

```
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command')
parser_config = subparsers.add_parser('config', help='Configuration')
parser_run = subparsers.add_parser('run', help='Execute operation on device')

parser_run.add_argument('d',  type=str, ...)
parser_run.add_argument('o',  type=str, ...)
parser_run.add_argument('-v', type=int, nargs='*', ...)

# later:

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.command == 'config':
    print('Configuration')
else:
    print('Run operation')
```

Used from the command line as:

```
$ manageAdam config
# or
$ manageAdam run <device> <operation> <values...>
```

Comment: I am using this solution as I think that the subparsers builds my script in a more intuitive way. But just if anyone else needs other way of doing it, using the nargs='?' option makes the positional arguments not mandatory so then it can be done with further checking after parsing the args. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no such way.

You can make all arguments optional and set default value to `None` then perform check that all of them aren't `None` otherwise raise `argparse.ArgumentError`, if `manageAdam` provided skip check for other arguments.